# SwiftUI - notifications and moving to new view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to generate a notification upon the press of a button, and clicking the notification causes a different tab in tab view to be selected?

Alternatively, if that’s not possible, cause the tab “button” to change to a different colour so that the user knows to navigate to that tab once the notification has generated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: Why would you need a notification for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it-

**Request Permission**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
    if success {
        print("All set!")
    } else if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**Schedule Notification**

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Feed the cat"
content.subtitle = "It looks hungry"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

// show this notification five seconds from now
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

// choose a random identifier
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

// add our notification request
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

You can follow along [this tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-local-notication-tutorial) for more details